# How do I pass a visual range to a function without numbers or using :command in vim?

Tags: vim

How do I pass a visual selection to a function from a script and **NOT** command line / mapping. I was wondering if something like this was possible? Or if there is a function that gets a range ?

What I want:

```
:call LowerToUpper('<,'>)
:call LowerToUpper(GetVisualRange())
```

NOT THIS

```
:call LowerToUpper(1,5)
command! -range Edit call LowerToUpper(<line1>,<line2>)
:'<,'>LowerToUpper
```

Here is the function example:

```
function! LowerToUpper(first,last) abort
for lineno in range(a:first,a:last)
    let line = getline(lineno) 
    let newLine= substitute(line, '\v(\w)','\U\1','g')
    call setline(lineno,newLine)
endfor
endfunction
```

The solution might be a hack to make a function that returns the visual selection GetVisualSelection().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> :call LowerToUpper('<,'>)

You're very very close. Use [`line()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#line()) to get lines of the marks:

```
:call LowerToUpper(line("'<"), line("'>"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have your function with `range` modifier.

```
function! LowerToUpper() abort range
    for lineno in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
        let line = getline(lineno)
        let newLine = substitute(line, '\v(\w)','\U\1','g')
        call setline(lineno, newLine)
    endfor
endfunction

'<,'>call LowerToUpper()
```

This mostly serves as a shortcut for passing `line("'<")` and `line("'>")` implicitly. The argument names `a:firstline` and `a:lastline` are fixed.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Do you know how I can execute in Normal mode one line and visual mode?? I tried to get the mode with mode() here is the code :                                                        ```function! RunLineCmd() abort range
 let comment ='\v\c^[ \t:]*(\/\/|#|")(\s+)?'
 for num in range(a:firstline,a:lastline)
 let line=getline(num)
 if match(line,comment) != -1
  let line=substitute(line,'\v^.{-}"','','g')
  execute line
 else
  execute line
 endif
 endfor
endfunction
"map <leader>l :call RunLineCmd(getline('.'))<cr>
map <leader>l :'<,'>call RunLineCmd()<cr>```

Comment: @ritchie Line range on pressing `:` is input "full-auto"; and `mode()` will become Normal after `<CR>`.